# Migrate values of one database table into another table with different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new to SQL, so I think this will have a simple answer, but I'm having trouble tracking down a comparable example via google.

I have two tables in a SQL database with similar values, but a different number of columns with different column names. I need to migrate the the values from the first database (catalog_product_entity_tier_price) into the second database (mb_tierprices_list) and then fill in the gaps with a default value.

This is where I'm up to:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_tier_price (entity_id, website_id, qty, value) 
SELECT entity_id, website_id, price_qty, percent
FROM mb_tierprices_list;
```

But I also need to handle three more columns in catalog_product_entity_tier_price with default values:

```
value_id (this is set to AUTO_INCREMENT, so nothing to do there)
all_groups = 1
customer_group_id = 0
```

Should I split this into two queries and just do a second one like so:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_tier_price (all_groups, customer_group_id) 
VALUES (1, 0);
```

Is there a preferred way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the default values in your select like this:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_tier_price (entity_id, website_id, qty, value, all_groups, customer_group_id) 
SELECT entity_id, website_id, price_qty, percent, 1, 0
FROM mb_tierprices_list;
```